# Dynamics CRM Online Trial - add user

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I am able to access a trial instance without issue. I've added another user though the office 365 portal, they have a professional license. In CRM, I've given them the system admin role. When they login, that user only has the 'Dashboards' section available under Sales and Marketing, but can get to all the Settings items. I've tried to assign accounts to them, but when I do that, I get a message stating they don't have permissions to be assigned records (yet they're sys admin). On the Sales and Marketing dashboards, all the sections state that the user doesn't have permissions. Other than setting them up in the office portal and giving them a role in CRM what else can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Needed to set Access Mode = read/write on the user record in CRM (not in O365)